# How do GET requests respond differently to a Server VS a Curl requests?

Tags: node.js, rest, caching, curl, server

I am making a Node.js/Express backend for a mobile app that makes requests to an API using the RESTful approach, where I can use the JSON data returned by this API for users to use in my mobile app.

My confusion lies in the differences that go on '*under to hood*' and what automatically get handled when using **specific headers** that are intended for browsers and a server **VS** when making **curl request** through the terminal, that you'll run more than once, sending and responding with different headers

### Headers/The Rules That Apply I Make Requests

I must use the conditional GETs convention where:

> 1) **All responses return an HTTP Cache-Control header**. It’s content indicates how long a cached response can be used to reduce unnecessary API requests.
>
> 2) In addition to that, each response **returns an HTTP ETag header**. It’s content is to be used in subsequent requests to the same resource in an HTTP **If-None-Match** header. The API will then return a status code 304 Not Modified if the cached information is still valid.
>
> *Clients accessing the This API MUST use this techniques, also known as conditional GET.*

### Using Curl Requests

---

#### Making Initial Request:

A) Returns the **data** I requested. 
B) Returns an **Etag** to use for future requests 
 C) Returns a **Cache-Control** header to know how long the data is cache-able, like so:

---

First Request:

```
$ curl -v "https://api.example.com/data/3" -X GET \                 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -u token:secret
```

Responce:

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 01 Sep 2017 22:22:22 GMT
< ETag: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                    <-----Got Etag
< Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 11:11:11 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private               <-----and Cache-Control is set 
{"data":{"id":1, "...": "..."}}                            to 3600 seconds (1 hour).
```

Here I understand the `Cache-Control` header specifies that the data I just got is good for 3,600 seconds, i.e. 1 hour. So I can use the returned data-information for the next hour without having to request the data from the API again. After that time period, another request can be made to the API. This time I include the returned `xxx.....` `ETag` value I got one hour ago (because thats how long the `Cache-Control` was set for), and use it in the `If-None-Match` header if I make another request like so:

#### Making Another Curl Request:

---

Future Request:

```
$ curl -v "https://api.example.com/data/3" -X GET \                 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "If-None-Match: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"               <--Added here
    -u token:secret
```

Future Responce:

```
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified                          <--Got 304 because the 
 < Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 20:24:20 GMT
< ETag: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"                    <-- `Etag` returned is the same 
< Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Sep 2015 11:45:39 GMT         (so I know it hasn't changed)
< Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private
< Connection: close
```

So this leads to me having a few questions:

### Making None-Curl Requests (via a Node.js server):

---

I am using the pretty straight forward  Node.js [request](https://github.com/request/request) module to make my request like so:

```
 var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'https://api.example.com/data/3',
  headers: {                                     <------ Setting up Headers 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',          Note: no "If-None-Match"
     'Accept': 'application/json'
     'Authorization: Basic QQWERQWERWQER='
   }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = body                              <------ Got 200 response and loaded 
  }                                                   return data into data varible
}

request(options, callback);
```

---

### So how is my Express server communicating with this API when making requests?

So after I make my first request on my Express server, it (my server) can then determine if it needs to fetch that content from the network or from cache based on the `Cache-Control` header and `ETag`. So how is this being done?

Do I need to programmatically/write code to do that every hour? So will I have to write code to grab the `etag` like this

```
 if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = body;
var etag = response.headers.etag            <------ Grab this
      }
```

and create a second set of headers like this

```
 headers: {                                    
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',          
         'Accept': 'application/json'
         'Authorization: Basic QQWERQWERWQER='
          'if-none-match': etag           <------ Adding it here 
       }
```

like I had to do when did when I did my second curl? (I did this and it will hold up on every requests not returning any status code, if this is how its done could it just be I did something wrong on my end?)

or does the initial response where `Cache-Control` headers set to `max-age=3600, private` and the `Etag` (set to `xxxxxxxx` in my example) automatically set the cache on my Express server and tells it to act accordingly with the it wants this resource where it check it again in an hour without having to do anything to tell it to?

Right now whenever I request a resource in the mobile app that will need a something (lets say the resource in my example https://api.example.com/data/3 ) from this API it triggers my Express server to fetch it on mobile app users behalf and return it. However when I request the same resource more than once, the API returns a 200 response every time. Where as it should be responding with a 304 for every request after the first. So what's going on here/ what am I doing/ understanding wrong? why would I not get 304 response?